# Verify JtextFiled in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I very new to java language:
I want to know if I want to how I can  check the input value of text filed  and verify it. If it is verified then insert to data base but if it is not verified do not do any actions.
just show error message.
Another question is that: one of my field is ID and i want to define an ID as a unique number.
here is my code:

Comment: *"verify it"*  Verify it as what?  A particular known pattern? One of a collection of values defined in the DB? ..

Comment: So far I count 4 questions, you might want to trim that down and focus on a single problem or the question might be marked as too broad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if I want to how I can check the input value of text filed and verify it

There are any number of ways you might achieved this...

You could...

- Use an `InputVerifier`, as discussed in [How to Use the Focus Subsystem, Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification), which allows you to do post validation on the field
- Use a `DocumentFilter`, as discussed in [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter), which allows you to do real time validation
- Use a `JFormattedTextField`, [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and/or `JSpinner`, [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), which will allow to restrict what the user can enter, but this is, again, post validated.
- Just run through a list or array of the fields and verify each one when the user hits the "save" button, to be frank, this is really a bad idea and is just plain annoying.

> If it is verified then insert to data base

This will come down to how you implement the validation routines, but you should look at [JDBC(TM) Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for the basics of interacting with databases...

> but if it is not verified do not do any actions. just show error message

Start by taking a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

> Another question is that: one of my field is ID and i want to define an ID as a unique number

Generally speaking, the database should take care of record identities/keys/IDs, as it will also take care of multi user access and further prevent the possibility that multiple users will try and use the same ID...

Comment: @KickButtowski Yeah, I'm pretty good at babbling and not saying much ;)

Comment: if you tell me sky is not blue, I totally agree with you . hope I answered your comment ;)